# svnx alternative for windows

Tags: svn, svnx

I just had to change to a windows laptop from mac, cause my mac is broken atm.
so now I need an alternative for svnx, running on windows, really quickly!
so I need a stand alone client, with which I can get my repositories from the server, review older versions of the rep and update the files to the server
I have not been able to find anything remotely similar so far.
I would be really grateful for any tips!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I find [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) to be a fine GUI for using SVN in a windows environment.

As your comment indicates, you have evaluated TortoiseSVN and would prefer a stand alone client and not one integrated into Windows Explorer, my next search result, `svn client windows -tortoise`, yields [RapidSVN](http://rapidsvn.tigris.org/) [RapidSVN screenshots](http://rapidsvn.tigris.org/screenshots.html) vs [svnx screenshot](http://svnx.googlecode.com/svn/wiki/svnX-1.3-big.png)

Comment: @J.A.W. If you find an answer helpful, you can click the Up arrow. If it solves your problem, there should be an outline of a checkmark next to the answer. Marking questions as answered helps future readers determine which avenue they should pursue first to resolve their issue.

Comment: @billinkc upvote his question and he will be able to upvote the answer soon.

Comment: @bahrep absolutely incorrect. Anyone can upvote answers on their own questions at any time (or I have been absolutely sorely misled).

Answer (score 2):

[SmartSVN](http://www.smartsvn.com/) is good (cross-platform) SVN-client

Answer (score 1):

Tortoisesvn is great. I'm not familiar with svnx, but it should provide similar functionality:
http://tortoisesvn.net/

Comment: I tried that but I need a stand alone client with window mode, cause I'm used to that :(

Comment: @J.A.W. It would be helpful to amend your question then with all the criteria you would require to satisfy your needs.

Comment: true ;) sorry
so I need a stand alone client, with which I can get my repositories from the server, review older versions of the rep and update the files to the server :)

Comment: @J.A.W. Excellent, but you'll want to scroll up to the top and click the Edit button and incorporate your feature list into the original question. Comments are used for clarification and should be not be for documenting actual needs.